# How to convert circle feature to polygon feature in Openlayers2?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I have features with [circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svKdV.png) style
and I want change circle to some polygon like rectangle. How can I do this?
I can use [Regular Shapes](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/regularshape.html) in Openlayers 4 but what about Openlayers 2 ?

Comment: the question is not clear, can you give us an example of circle and rectangle.

Comment: var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(prevLoadedFeatures[j].geometry,prevLoadedFeatures[j].attributes); Create point feature with red color style. I want change circle to polygon. something like [Regular Shapes](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/regularshape.html)

Comment: I think you would need to use the `externalGraphic` option.  You could create a simple rectangle as data URL.

Comment: Thanks. the externalGraphic option worked for me.